# AHK Script with ImageSearch

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote script that automatically detects play button on the screen and clicks it.

Here it is:

```
SetTimer Go, 1000

CoordMode Pixel, Screen
CoordMode Mouse, Screen

^!r:: Reload

F4::T4 := !T4

F5::play()


Go:
    If (!T4){
        return
    }
    play()
return

play(){
    FoundX := 0
    FoundY := 0
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, play2.png
    If (ErrorLevel = 2){
        MsgBox Could not conduct the search.
    }
    Else{
        If (ErrorLevel = 1){
            return
        }
        Else{
            x :=  FoundX + 40
            y :=  FoundY + 40
            MouseClick, left, x, y
        }
    }
}
```

While in regular window it works fine in fullscreen (fullscreened borderless window) it's behaving weird.

For example sometimes when it sees the button it clicks but then keeps clicking even thou its not on the screen anymore. What's more even if i reload the script it would still keep clicking in that spot. After pressing play a fast-forward button which is fairly similar. Does `ImageSearch` have some tolerance settings?

The other sorcery is that when i change focus to another window (which is on top but the play button is still visible) it clicks, which change the focus back, and will not click anymore even after the button is back. However if use `ALT+TAB` to go back to that other window it triggers.

Can anyone explain to me wth is going on here?

Comment: Don't know about the whole question but `CoordMode Pixel, Screen` is never executed. it needs to be above any hotkey definition. You also need to use the same mode for the `MouseClick` with `CoordMode Mouse, Screen`.

Comment: Those 2 changes made no difference. In both cases the windows starts in upper right corner of the screen so i guess it does not matter. If `MouseClick` triggers at all it does so in the right point so `CoordMode` is not the issue.

Comment: For debugging purposes, have you popped up the ErrorLevel? Perhaps you're getting an error other than 1 or 2.

Comment: Image Search doesn't have tolerance settings which is a pain. If you search for OCR stuff you'll find a library which doesn't really do OCR but does a pixelwise monochrome search. That code does have tolerance settings that can work in this setting.